# Visual Studio 2015 update3/cordova update 10 bug for apk building?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I've updated my Visual Studio to "Update 3" and the newest cordorva as of 7/7/2016, basically I applied all the updates. And it seems failed my app.

There is the following code in the html file `templates\events.html`.

```
<div class="events-2colmn-l backgnd-cover" ui-sref="menu.music">
    MUSIC
</div>
```

In route.js

```
  .state('menu.music', {
    url: '/music',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/music.html',
        controller: 'musicCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

There is a service.js file.

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('EventService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://....azurewebsites.net/api/events/:id', { id: "@id" });
}]);
```

And in the controller there is

```
.controller('musicCtrl', function ($scope, EventService) { // called twice when clicked
    var allEvents = EventService.query({ category: "Music" });
    allEvents.$promise.then(function (response) { 
        $scope.events = response;  // response is undefined after updates
    });
})
```

The parameter `response` is `undefined` when debugging using "Google Android Emulator" (Side-loading on phones got the same behaving so it should also get `undefined`). However, `response` got the right value when running in Ripple or built by Visual studio before applying the updates.

Is there any workaround?

**Update:**
I clicked the earliest call in "Call STack" when debugging in emulator and find the following code was called in ionic.bundle.js.

```
  xhr.onload = function requestLoaded() {
    var statusText = xhr.statusText || ''; // statusText is "Not found" but xhr is null
    ......
    completeRequest(callback, // call stack 
        status, // 404
        response, // ""
        xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(), // xhr is null
        statusText); // Not found
```

However the cursor on `status` and it shows 404. The url has the correct value of "https://....azurewebsites.net/.....".

And I tried opening a browser in emulator and I can access internet the link and got the webapi output.

**Update 2:**
There is one thing different between ripple and emulator. I set breakpoints as following. The ripple will break on both after click the item. However, in emulator, the first time the code will only break on the first breakpoint, continue running then break both the breakpoints.

```
.controller('musicCtrl', function ($scope, EventService) {
    var allEvents = EventService.query({ category: "Music" }); // Emulator stops twice here
    allEvents.$promise.then(
        function (response) { 
            $scope.events = response; }, // Ripple stops here after one top break
        function (e) { 
            console.log(e); } // Emulator stops here after two top breaks
        );
})
```

Comment: Please check if the internet for Google Android Emulator is available.

Comment: @ElvisXia It should be available. I remember I tried the browser inside the emulator and I kept getting the emails.

Comment: Sorry for late response, did you get any error message?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Hi Elvis, I've updated the question for some newly found.

Comment: 'xhr is null'. It seems like codes related, could you share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT The problem is the code works when run in ripple or on my friend's visual studio which is not updated.

Comment: Could you please try using Fiddler in your android device to catch the data transfering of your app? Here is a document about [Config Fiddler for Android](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid).

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I tried fiddler. There is no traffic at all when I ran the app built on my environment. It shows "Tunnel to ...azurewebsites.net..." when running the app built with my friend's PC. And my built even doesn't show the background image (which should be displayed before the actual content is rendered)

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 - I work on the Visual Studio Cordova tooling team, would you mind emailing me a sample project that demonstrates this issue (in other words, create a sample project with just the code that errors - not your full app code). My email is jomatthi -at- Microsoft-dot-com